# limit of the first moment of solution of stochastic differential equation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose $X^x$ is solution of
$$d X_t = X^3_t dW_t, \quad X_0 = x>0.$$
In the above, $W$ is a Brownian motion in a given filtered probability space. Such an equation has unique strong solution, since $x^3$ is locally lipschitz. In fact, it is a strict local martingale starting from initial $x$.

[Q.]  Anybody could either prove or disprove 
$$\lim_{(y,t) \to (x,0)} \mathbb E [X_t^y] = x ?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. limit in t.   $X_t$ is a positive local martingale, hence  a supermartingale so the limit as $t \rightarrow 0$ exists and is $\le x$.  On the other hand, by path continuity $X_t \approx x$ for small t, so $\mathbb E^x X_t > x - \epsilon $ for those same t.
2. Continuity in y. I think must follow from monotonicity  in y and continuity in t

Comment: I do not see the argument from path continuity.

Comment: 1.  You are ok with the limit being $< x$ from the supermartingale argument ?   2.  You are ok with path continuity, but not the implication about the limit ?  3.  the simple argument is $X_t \rightarrow x$ as $t \rightarrow 0 $ a.s. and since $X_t > 0, \mathbb E^x X_t > (x - \epsilon) \mathbb P^x (X_t > x - \epsilon)  \rightarrow (x - \epsilon)$

Comment: Mike, Thanks. Now I finally understand. Cheers.